# Confusion about direct limit of vector spaces

Tags: direct-sum, limits-colimits, direct-product

Consider the sequence  of vector spaces
$i_n : \mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^{n+1}$
given by the inclusions $x\mapsto (x,0)$.

We can consider the direct limit of this sequence, call it
$\mathbb R^\infty$.

This object is defined by the universal property that any collection of homomorphisms $\phi_n:\mathbb R^n\to Y$ such that $\phi_{n+1}\circ i_n = \phi_n $ induces a map
$u:\mathbb R^\infty\to Y$ such that the obvious diagram commutes.

It seems to me that this definition is satisfied by both $\bigoplus_{i\geq 0} \mathbb R$ and  $\prod_{i\geq 0} \mathbb R$ because for each $n$ they split as
$\mathbb R^n \oplus \bigoplus_{i> n} \mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R^n \oplus \prod_{i> n} \mathbb R$.
However the two are not isomorphic.

What am I missing here ?

Comment: Side note: if we instead consider the sequence of *projections* (not inclusions) $\dots \to  \mathbb Z^3  \to  \mathbb Z^2 \to \mathbb Z$, then the *inverse* limit (not direct) is the infinite product $\prod_{i=1}^\infty \mathbb Z$, so that $\prod_{i=1}^\infty \mathbb Z\to \dots \mathbb Z^{n+1}\to \mathbb Z^{n}\to \dots \mathbb Z$.
In a sense this helps to recall the names, injective limit (i.e. direct) as the limit of the inclusions $\mathbb Z^n\to \mathbb Z^{n+1}\to \dots \to \bigoplus_i^\infty \mathbb Z$. And projective limit (i.e. inverse) as the limit of the projections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not satisfied by the infinite product. Consider the natural sequence of inclusions $\phi_n : \mathbb{R}^n \to \bigoplus_{i \ge 0} \mathbb{R}$; by the universal property we get a map $\mathbb{R}^{\infty} \to \bigoplus_{i \ge 0} \mathbb{R}$ which of course is an isomorphism. We do *not* get a map $\prod_{i \ge 0} \mathbb{R} \to \bigoplus_{i \ge 0} \mathbb{R}$ because there is nowhere for the sequences which are not finitely supported to go. This map would have to be a retract of the inclusion $\bigoplus_{i \ge 0} \mathbb{R} \to \prod_{i \ge 0} \mathbb{R}$ and I believe it is consistent with ZF + the negation of the axiom of choice that no such retract exists; even assuming AC, such a retract is not unique, which contradicts the uniqueness part of the universal property.